Array shifting in C
I want to shift the element in array like
If n = 3
I want output to be like:
1 2 3
3 1 2
2 3 1

My output has to have n rows
I’ve tried this but it doesn’t work
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    int lines[n]; int i,j;
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        lines[i] = (i+1) % 10;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        for(j=n;j>0;j--) {
            printf("%d ", lines[(i+j)%n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

It has something wrong at the first line but I don’t know what to do.

What's your current output?

I got n = 4 —>
1 4 3 2
2 1 4 3
3 2 1 4
4 3 2 1

Please [edit] your question to show both the input and the actual output.

You can just treat the array as a ring (circular) buffer, e.g. for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { printf (" %d", arr[(j + n - i) % n]); } putchar ('\n'); }

You need to run the outer loop backwards and the inner loop forwards.  The outer loop controls the rotation amount, and the inner loop controls the direction the values are printed in (left-to-right).
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n; scanf("%d", &n);
    int lines[n]; int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
        lines[i] = (i+1) % 10;
    }

    for(i=n;i>0;i--) {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) {
            printf("%d ", lines[(i+j)%n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

Output for 3:
1 2 3 
3 1 2 
2 3 1 

Output for 4:
1 2 3 4 
4 1 2 3 
3 4 1 2 
2 3 4 1 


Wrong arithmetics. Here you have a function which prints shifted values in both directions.
void shift(const int *array, const size_t size, const int direction)
{
    for(size_t i=0;i<size;i++) {
        for(size_t j=0;j<size;j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[(direction ? (size - i+j) : i+j)%size]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() {
    size_t n; scanf("%zu", &n);
    int lines[n]; 
    
    for(size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        lines[i] = (i+1) % (n+1);
    }
    shift(lines, n, 0);    
    printf("\n");
    shift(lines, n, 1);    
}

https://godbolt.org/z/r831hM15j
Output:
1 2 3 
2 3 1 
3 1 2 

1 2 3 
3 1 2 
2 3 1 

